# Expiation for breaking an oath

Tags: oaths

If a person promised to Allah, that is i will do such and such if i get such and such, but afterwards that person broke the promises. 
What is the expiation for breaking this type of oath. 
How to do repentance?

Answer (score 1):

The expiation is fasting 3 days, or feeding 10 poor persons out of what you would provide for your family or yourself, or providing clothing to 10 poor persons out of what you would provide for yourself, in the hanafi madhab you can donate money for it and certain organizations calculate it, how much you need to give.

Comment: Fasting 3 days is only for when you can not afford feeding\clothing.

Comment: Please provide references. Is expiation of oath applicable if we break promise to Allah? I thought it was only if we break promises that we made to other people.